# ¿Qué formato es este: '2005-10-09 07:31:00.151'?

Tags: sql, datetime

Alguien podría indicarme cual es ese formato, tengo el siguiente problema, quiero hacer un `UPDATE`, lo corre sin inconveniente pero no realiza la actualizaciòn. Quiero pensar que es por que no estoy indicando los ùltimos 3 nùmeros, solamente dejo el formato en `aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

Por eso quiero saber como representar los 3 últimos.

```
UPDATE K_Horario 
SET FechaCreacion='2017/07/14 09:53:12' 
WHERE Hora ='2017/07/20 20:00:00.000' AND FechaCreacion LIKE '2017/07/24 19:31:47'
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has buscado/investigado? El que digas tener "un problema grande" no ayuda, mejor describe la situación. Véase [ask].

Comment: Creo que es DATETIME ISO 8601.

Comment: Hola Rubèn lo que pasa es que no me hace un UPDATE por que lo represento solo hasta los segundos y supongo que ese es el problema ya que no estoy indicando los 3 ultimos nùmeros en el WHERE

Comment: Hola Ismael, pero quisiera saber como lo represento , se que hasta segunds es "aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm:ss", pero no se como representar los ùltimos 3 numeros

Comment: Deberías agregar la descripción a la pregunta. Los comentarios son para pedir aclaración o criticar las publicaciones, no para dar información relevante sobre la publicación.

Comment: Bienvenido Ismael. Por favor revisa [answer].

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que has realizado?

Comment: Al `like` le falta algún comodín, por ejemplo el `%`. `UPDATE K_Horario SET 
 FechaCreacion='2017/07/14 09:53:12' 
WHERE
 Hora ='2017/07/20 20:00:00.000' 
 AND FechaCreacion LIKE '2017/07/24 19:31:47%'`

Comment: Que tipo de dato es el campo Hora y el campo FechaCreacion??  son DataTime??

Answer (score 2):

Al momento de filtrar utiliza los formatos para que el `where` te regrese resultados mira, tendrias que poner algo así:

Puedes probar antes de hacer el `update`:

```
select FechaCreacion, Hora
from K_Horario
where convert(varchar(8),Hora,114) = '20:00:00'--El formato esta para que se vea asi la hr
and convert(varchar(10),FechaCreacion,120)='2017-07-14'--Omite la hr en realidad es dificil adivinarle la hr exacta a la que se creo
```

Si la consulta anterior te regresa datos y sigues teneendo el error al intentar actualizar, 
¿podrías publicar el mensaje de error en tu pregunta?, por otra parte tal vez debas cambiar el `update` las `/` por `-` para la fecha, esto dependerá del idioma que le pusiste al `SQL` al instalarlo, si editas directamente los datos de una tabla puedes ver si la fecha... esta con formato `aaaa-mm-dd` o `aaaa/mm/dd`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Solo sería necesario considerar la fecha en formato ISO:

```
DECLARE @K_Horario TABLE
(
    Hora DATETIME
   ,FechaCreacion DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO @K_Horario
(
    Hora
   ,FechaCreacion
)
VALUES
('20170720 20:00:00.000', '20170724 19:31:47');

SELECT *
FROM @K_Horario;
```

> ```
> +-------------------------+-------------------------+
> |          Hora           |      FechaCreacion      |
> +-------------------------+-------------------------+
> | 2017-07-20 20:00:00.000 | 2017-07-24 19:31:47.000 |
> +-------------------------+-------------------------+
> ```

```
UPDATE @K_Horario
SET FechaCreacion = '20170714 09:53:12.00'
WHERE Hora = '20170720 20:00:00.000'
      AND FechaCreacion = '20170724 19:31:47.000';

SELECT *
FROM @K_Horario;
```

> ```
> +-------------------------+-------------------------+
> |          Hora           |      FechaCreacion      |
> +-------------------------+-------------------------+
> | 2017-07-20 20:00:00.000 | 2017-07-14 09:53:12.000 |
> +-------------------------+-------------------------+
> ```