# error fecha PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicacion con php codeigniter y sql server 2000.
Trato de hacer un insert a la bd  e insertar los datos pero la fecha que esta guardando es: 1894-07-07 00:00:00.0 (datetime) en vez de la fecha actual.

este es el codigo:

controlador:

```
public function Save(){
        $fk_idInd = $this->input->post('txtIdIind');
        $fechaHora = date("m-d-Y");
        $hora = $this->input->post('txtHora');
        $estado = 1;
        $rut_res = '123456';
        $this->Indicaciones_model->insertControl($fk_idInd,$fechaHora,$estado,$rut_res);

    }
```

modelo:

```
public function insertControl($fk_idInd,$fechaHora,$estado,$rut_res){
        $sql = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO HCE_CONTROL_I_MED(FK_I_MED,FECHA_HORA,ESTADO,RUT_RES)
                                    VALUES($fk_idInd,$fechaHora,$estado,$rut_res)");
        return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
    }
```

alguna idea de lo que esta pasando?

Comment: hola, ya intentaste imprimir el query antes del insert? si te das cuenta, el formato de fecha por estándar es **yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss** y tu estas mandando la fecha al revés **dd-mm-yyyy**, no se si pase lo mismo con la hora

Comment: esto es lo que imprimo desde el modelo; VALUES(9699,2017-09-26,1,123456)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El formato por defecto para insertar en base de datos es

```
$fechaHora = date("Y-m-d");
```

intenta realizar un replace, en ocasiones me ha pasado que no inserta la fecha correctamente por que el formato viene mal, intenta con esta función.

```
if (isset($_POST['txt_fecha'])) {
$apidate = $_POST['txt_fecha'];
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $apidate);
$fecha = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

}

Comment: de esa forma me guadra esta fecha : 1905-04-11 00:00:00.0

Answer (score 1):

Cuando trabajas con base de datos SQL Server deberías considerar enviar la fecha en formato ISO, así evitar incompatiblidad con la estructura de fecha.

En tu caso deberías considerar:

```
$fechaHora = date("Ymd"); // 20170926
```

O sino, si quieres que considere la fecha actual del servidor donde está la base de datos deberías utilizar `GETDATE()`:

```
$sql = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO HCE_CONTROL_I_MED(FK_I_MED,FECHA_HORA,ESTADO,RUT_RES) VALUES($fk_idInd, GETDATE(), $estado, $rut_res)");
```

---

- [GETDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql)
- [¿Qué formato es este: '2005-10-09 07:31:00.151'?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90861)